# How would I restrict certain user levels from editing categories

Tags: users

I have a situation where I need WooCommerce product categories to be edited by an admin only.

So, basically I'm looking for a way to prevent other user roles from adding, editing or deleting categories for posts.

Comment: Please search the site for `current_user_can` and improve your question with some code. So far you question is too broad and will get closed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to remove the capability for a Editor role to manage_categories

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_editor_manage_categories' ); 

function remove_editor_manage_categories() {

$role = get_role( 'editor' );
$role->remove_cap( 'manage_categories' );
}
```

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap

Comment: Woocommerce also has a role called shop manager, need to make sure this role cannot edit either